# About conjugation class functions in abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $H$ a subgroup if $G$. If we denote $\mathcal{C}(G)$ to the set of maps $\phi:G\to \mathbb{C}$ which are constant in a conjugation class. If $(-)_H:\mathcal{C}(G)\rightarrow\mathcal{C}(H)$ is the restriction function to $H$ show that $(-)_H$ is surjective and identify its kernel.

My attempt: Since $G$ is abelian, every conjugation class has only one element, so if $\phi\in \mathcal{C}(H)$ then by giving if ramdom values in the rest of the elements of $G$ we have the surjectivity. The kernel is giving by the functions which are $0$ in $H$. Am I right? Is there a better interpretation in the context of representation theory?

Comment: Probably you want the maps to be maps of groups, so that $\phi(g^2)=\phi(g)^2$.  Probably also the maps should go to $\mathbb{C}^*$ ( to emphasize we're looking at multiplicative group ).  Say $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, $H=\{0,2\}$, and $\phi\in \mathcal{C}(H)$ given by $\phi(2)=-1$.  Then extending to $\mathcal{C}(G)$ we have to have either $\phi(1)=i$ or $\phi(1)=-i$.  You can't choose randomly.

Comment: I don`t want maps of groups and they should go to $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: So the maps are just set maps?  Do you have any structure on $\mathcal{C}(G)$? It sounds like you have a group structure given by pointwise addition.  In that case, I agree with your analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.

A bit representation theoretic way to prove this — I wouldn't say this is a better interpretation — is showing a [section map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphism) explicitly, i.e., proving
$$\left(\frac{1}{\lvert G : H \rvert}\theta^G\right)_H = \theta$$ 
for every class function $\theta$ of $H$. This is just a degenerated identity of the [Mackey decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory#Mackey_decomposition).